# windows xp application error (application made in visual studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

i make simple c++ console program in visual studio and got release files, when i copy them to my old windows xp computer program says:

> ConsoleApplication.exe is not valid win32 application.

i have no idea how to fix that :/...

Comment: Maybe you actually wrote a C++/CLI (AKA managed AKA non-native) application, and the XP machine doesn't have the .NET Framework installed?

Comment: about .NET i am not sure, probably doesnt... does xp machine must have same version of .NET as in my computer?

Comment: Can you upload the exe somewhere and link it here?

Comment: sure @MatteoItalia, here it is: https://mega.nz/#F!bR8HEQxI!MmhfWlPDZ8NM7NV1eL50yA